# netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist

Tags: batch-file, asp-classic, netsh

I've setup a basic index.asp page that allows me to input an IP address then triggers a batch file which adds that IP to the local security policy filter list. the command my bat file runs:

```
netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist="Blocked IPs" srcaddr=%1 dstaddr=any
```

If I trigger the batch file manually from the command line it works fine and the IP is added. However if I trigger it from the webpage nothing is added to the filter list...I tested by adding "mkdir c:\%1" as the first line in the batch file and it successfully made a folder named with the IP address so I have verified that its properly getting triggered and receiving the variable. Another thing I noticed if I use the same command but specify a remote computer it works.

```
netsh -r servername -u username -p password ipsec static add filter filterlist="Blocked IPs" srcaddr=%1 dstaddr=any
```

It will apply it to the remote computer's filterlist, so I tried just pointing back to localhost or even the local server name & IP but no difference.

Here is the code for the .asp page

```
<%
      if (Request.QueryString("ipaddress") <> "") then
      Response.Write ("start")

      Dim wshell, intReturn
      set wshell = server.createobject("wscript.shell")
      intReturn = wshell.run("C:\inetpub\test.bat " & Request.QueryString("ipaddress"), 0, True)
      Response.Write( intReturn )
      set wshell = nothing
                              response.write Request.querystring("ipaddress")                                  
      Response.Write ("end")
      else
%>
<html>
      <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      </head>
       <body>
       <center>
       <form action="index.asp" method="get">
       <br/>
            <input name="ipaddress" type="text">
      <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit">
       <form>
       </center>
       </body>
</html>
<% end if %>
```